# I am getting a warning when I sudo apt update: "doesn't have the component 'stella.cmit' "

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

Using Ubuntu 22.04, everything seems to be working but I am getting a warning when I `sudo apt update`.

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stella.cmit/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://hp.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stella.cmit' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Don't know if it is the cause but I noticed it after adding the `ppa` for `gpodder`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gpodder/pp
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-stella.cmit-aron-meta.list and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-stella.cmit-aron-meta.list.distUpgrade

deb http://hp.archive.canonical.com/ jammy stella
# deb-src http://hp.archive.canonical.com/ focal stella
deb http://hp.archive.canonical.com/ jammy stella.cmit
# deb-src http://hp.archive.canonical.com/ focal stella.cmit
```

From what I have read it sounded like it might be a problem with my `/etc/apt/sources.list` but I have no idea what I am looking at.

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04 _Focal_ - Build amd64 LIVE Binary 20220223-06:11]/ focal main

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
```

Comment: Show us the output of `grep -r 'stella.cmit' /etc/apt/` please.  This will help us narrow down where you're seeing weirdness in your source.lists - it's obvious that you're NOT using the standard repository mirrors as your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is entirely commented out for repos, so your configuration has to exist elsewhere.

Comment: Also, your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is commented out, all of it, not to mention that there are only `deb-src` lines.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the helpful answer and comments I received, especially the "grep -r 'stella.cmit' /etc/apt/". I navigated to the folder /etc/apt/sources.list.d and in the terminal I typed:

```
sudo mv oem-stella.cmit-aron-meta.list oem-stella.cmit-aron-meta.list.disabled
```

Still not sure what it was supposed to do but everything appears to be working and after rebooting the system I no longer get the warning. Not sure I had to reboot but that is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Use this script :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Detect os codename
codename=$(awk '/UBUNTU_CODENAME=/' /etc/os-release | sed 's/UBUNTU_CODENAME=//' | sed 's/[.]0/./')

# Disable all the external repos
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d && sudo bash -c 'for i in *.list; do mv ${i} ${i}.disabled; done' && cd /tmp

# Replace sources.list  
text="deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $codename main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $codename main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $codename-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $codename-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $codename-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $codename-updates main universe restricted multiverse"

sudo echo "$text" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list

# Start upgrade
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f -y
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt autoremove --purge -y
```

This will restore the default sources.list and disables all external repos.

source https://github.com/daboynb/linux_scripts

All inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d will be disabled. Enable ONLY what you need!

Example `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list.disabled /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list`